# R: display values in levelplot stratified by a grouping variable

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

In this following example, I need to display the values for each of the cells in each of the panels stratified by the grouping variable `class`:

```
library("lattice")
x <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=5)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=5)
r1 <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
r2 <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "/")))

grid1 <- grid2 <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid1$z <- cos(r1^2)*exp(-r1/(pi^3))
grid2$z <- cos(r2^2)*exp(-r2/(pi^3))
grid <- rbind(grid1, grid2)
grid$class <- c(rep("addition",length(x)^2), rep("division", length(x)^2))

p <- levelplot(z~x*y | factor(class), grid, 
               panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
                 panel.text(arg$x, arg$y, round(arg$z,1))})
print(p)
```

However, the cell values are superimposed on each other because the panel option dose not distinguish between the two groups. How can I get the values to display correctly in each group?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly behind the scenes, **lattice** uses an argument called `subscripts` to subset data for display in different panels. Often, it does so without you needing to be aware of it, but this is not one of those cases.

A look at the source code for `panel.levelplot`reveals that it handles `subscripts` on its own. `args(panel.levelplot)` shows that it's among the function's formal arguments, and the function's body shows how it uses them.

`panel.text()`, (really just a wrapper for `lattice:::ltext.default()`), on the other hand, doesn't know about or do anything with `subscripts`. From within a call to `panel.text(x,y,z)`, the `x`, `y`, and `z` that are seen are the full columns of the data.frame `grid`, which is why you saw the overplotting that you did.

To plot text for the values that are a part of the current panel, you need to make explicit use of the `subscripts` argument, like this:

```
myPanel <- function(x, y, z, ..., subscripts=subscripts) {
    panel.levelplot(x=x, y=y, z=z, ..., subscripts=subscripts)        
    panel.text(x = x[subscripts], 
               y = y[subscripts], 
               labels = round(z[subscripts], 1))
}
p <- levelplot(z~x*y | factor(class), grid, panel = myPanel)
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I have figured out a workaround by using `panel.number()` but your solution is more elegant.

Comment: You're very welcome. It was a good question, that finally gave me a better handle on when you do and don't need to mess around with subscripts.